# JSON Object from TextAreas

Tags: jquery, stringify

Im not sure if Im on the right path, but I want to convert text from the text areas to JSON Object.

The payload should look like this.

```
{
"intent":"SanFransico",
   "examples":[
    {
        "text":"San Fran"
    },
    {
        "text":"Bay Area"
    }
     ]
}
```

What I can do at the moment is sending in this textareas

```
   <textarea name="intent[intent]">SanFransico</textarea>
   <textarea name="intent[examples][text]">San Fran</textarea>
   <textarea name="intent[examples][text]">Bay Area</textarea>
```

unfortunately
 The payload that returns looks like this, and it does not return the second text field.

```
{
   "intent":
   {
    "intent":"SanFransico",
     "examples":{
         "text":"Bay Area"
     }
   }
}
```

I have a fiddler Im experimenting whit. 
https://jsfiddle.net/8w4tx1pk/

Any ideas if this is the right path? or do I need a more complicated function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing up your fiddle, I was able to address it.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8w4tx1pk/11/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="my-profile">
    <textarea name="intent">San Francisco</textarea>
    <textarea name="examples[][text]">San Fran</textarea>
    <textarea name="examples[][text]">Bay Area</textarea>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" id="btnSerialize" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">serializeToJSON</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea id="result" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnSerialize").on("click", function() {

    var obj = $('#my-profile').serializeJSON();
    console.log(obj);

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $("#result").val(jsonString);
  })
});
```

**Result**

```
{
  "intent":"San Francisco",
  "examples":[
    {
      "text":"San Fran"
    },{
      "text":"Bay Area"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much @Twisty.